# How to change the #size property of a select list of a selective exposed views filter?

Tags: views

I have a view with an exposed filter that is selective. Below is part of the array with the properties of the field. I need to set the #size to 20 but the code I'm using does nothing. Should be possible or not in this case?

$form array:

```
array(
  #info =>  array()
  name_selective    =>  array(
    #type   =>  select
    #options    =>  array()
    #default_value  =>  All
    #size   =>  null
    #validated  =>  true
```

My code:

```
function MYMODULE_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $form['name_selective']['#size'] = 20;
}
```

Comment: Is this hook being invoked at all?

Comment: Yes, it is. I'm degugging the $form array directly in the page inside that funciton.

Comment: Have you tried to let your hook implementation run last? With `hook_module_implements_alter`? And have you also tried it with just CSS?

Comment: I didn't use any of the solutions you suggested. Can you elaborate on how to do these?